# Javascript to auto animate carousel used together with controls

Tags: javascript, input, carousel, tailwind-css, checked

I have a carousel which has next and previous buttons as well as clickable indicator "blobs" to show which image is currently visible. It's built using only CSS and radio inputs with labels. (see https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/ for my starting point).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.carousel').forEach((carousel) => {
  animate_carousel(carousel);
  carousel.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']").forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
      animate_carousel(carousel);
    });
  });
});

function animate_carousel(carousel) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let radio = carousel.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    let next = carousel.querySelector('label.control-' + parseInt(radio.dataset.index, 10) + '.next');
    carousel.querySelector('input#' + next.getAttribute('for')).click();
    animate_carousel(carousel);
  }, 5000, carousel);
}
```

```css
.carousel-open:checked+.carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-item {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
}

[id^="carousel-"][id$="-0"]:checked~.control-0,
[id^="carousel-"][id$="-1"]:checked~.control-1,
[id^="carousel-"][id$="-2"]:checked~.control-2 {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

[id^="carousel-"][id$="-0"]:checked~.control-0~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
[id^="carousel-"][id$="-1"]:checked~.control-1~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
[id^="carousel-"][id$="-2"]:checked~.control-2~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
  color: #2b6cb0;
  /*Set to match the Tailwind colour you want the active one to be */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="carousel relative rounded-lg relative overflow-hidden shadow-xl border-4 bg-white border-white my-4">

  <div class="carousel-inner relative overflow-hidden rounded-b-md rounded-t-sm w-full">
    <input class="carousel-open" data-index="0" type="radio" id="carousel-1-0" name="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
    <div class="carousel-item absolute opacity-0 bg-center bg-no-repeat h-0 bg-cover" style="padding-bottom: 33.33%; background-image: url(https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/slides/054.jpg);"></div>
    <label for="carousel-1-1" class="control-0 w-8 h-8 ml-2 sm:ml-3 md:ml-4 lg:ml-5 md:ml-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden font-bold rounded-full leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 left-0 my-auto flex justify-center content-center">
    <
</label>
    <label for="carousel-1-1" class="next control-0 w-8 h-8 mr-2 sm:mr-3 md:mr-4 lg:mr-5 absolute cursor-pointer hidden rounded-full leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 right-0 my-auto">
    >
</label>

    <input class="carousel-open" data-index="1" type="radio" id="carousel-1-1" name="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
    <div class="carousel-item absolute opacity-0 bg-center bg-no-repeat h-0 bg-cover" style="padding-bottom: 33.33%; background-image: url(https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/slides/043.jpg);"></div>
    <label for="carousel-1-0" class="control-1 w-8 h-8 ml-2 sm:ml-3 md:ml-4 lg:ml-5 md:ml-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden font-bold rounded-full leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 left-0 my-auto flex justify-center content-center">
    <
</label>
    <label for="carousel-1-0" class="next control-1 w-8 h-8 mr-2 sm:mr-3 md:mr-4 lg:mr-5 absolute cursor-pointer hidden rounded-full leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 right-0 my-auto">
    >
</label>

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li class="inline-block">
        <label for="carousel-1-0" class="carousel-bullet cursor-pointer text-xs block text-white hover:text-blue-700 opacity-75">
                •
            </label>
      </li>
      <li class="inline-block">
        <label for="carousel-1-1" class="carousel-bullet cursor-pointer text-xs block text-white hover:text-blue-700 opacity-75">
                •
            </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make this automatically scroll through the images every 5 seconds. This works unless I click the buttons to manually navigate through the images. Then it returns the following error.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeNamedItem' on
> 'NamedNodeMap': No item with name 'checked' was found.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error though as there does appear to be a checked input.

Comment: I don't get what the point of that line is supposed to be in the first place. Setting another radio button in a radio button group `checked`, will remove the checked state from all other radios in that group automatically.

Comment: @CBroe That's what I thought, however it only works the first time if I don't include that. It then gets stuck on the second image in the carousel

Comment: The whole thing currently doesn't appear to work properly at all, after clicking these indicators a couple of times, the whole thing speeds up ... You have `animate_carousel` call itself at the end, so in combination with setTimeout, that is basically the same as an interval. But then when these indicators get clicked, ypu call `animate_carousel` again - so you have effectively multiple such timer intervals running in parallel.